# java: sums up the number using command line arguments

Tags: java

About sums up the number using command line arguments.
For example

```
    java  sum  "1 2 3"    <--"1 2 3" will be args[0]
    the sum is 6
```

How can i calculate it?
I want the code of this program.
Thank
This code only can calculate when i input
java  sum 1 2 3
but i want input
java  sum  "1 2 3"

```
public class sum {
public static void main( String args[] ) {
int num=0;
for(int i=0; i<args.length; i++){
   num+= Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}

  System.out.println("The sum is " + num);
   }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking? the Java implementation? You need to show us the code you tried to write, SO won't write it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First create a counter, initialise at zero.
- Split the "1 2 3" string on spaces, using `args[0].split(" ");` and assign it to a new array.
- Loop through all the elements of the new array.
- Parse every element to an integer using `Integer.parseInt(String);`
- Add the parsed value to the counter.
- Print the result.

Comment: Read the instruction "split the "1 2 3" string on spaces using args[0].split(" ") and assign it to a new array"

Comment: @AshishTyagi: I added that line after he wrote that comment :) But indeed, maybe I had to notify him I edited my answer.

Comment: thank you, i rewriting the code